# How to handle Ajax Response with MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im using jquery mobile as well to add to the fun.
What I want to do is simply do a post and remain on the same page, however im being redirected to the login page, popup works but I then end up on the login page.

```
  function UpdateClient(data) {
                var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("MobileAppointmentEdit")';
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {Id:'@Model.Id' },
                    success: function(response) {
                       $("#popupSaved").popup();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MobileAppointmentEdit(MobileAppointment appointment)
        {
            if (appointment !=null)
            {

//Do stuff

            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us how do you call `UpdateClient` function. I have a feeling that is being called from button or anchor and you are trying to prevent the defautl action with the `return false` statement in `success` callback (btw. the `success` is being called in different scope so the `return false` there will not cause `UpdateClient` to return false - this function is long exited before the `success` callback gets called).

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Save"  data-theme="b" onclick="UpdateClient()" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be returning false from the success AJAX callback but this doesn't make any sense. It looks like you are calling this `UpdateClient` function from the submit button of some form. Make sure that you return false from this function in order to cancel the default action. For example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return UpdateClient();" />
```

and then return false from the function itself:

```
function UpdateClient(data) {
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("MobileAppointmentEdit")';
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: '@Model.Id' },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#popupSaved").popup();
        }
    });

    return false; // <!-- here, that's the important bit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
function UpdateClient(data) {
                var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("MobileAppointmentEdit")';
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'json'
                    data: {Id:'@Model.Id' },
                    success: function(response) {
                     if(response.Success)
                     {  
                       $("#popupSaved").popup();
                     }
                   else{
                       $("#popupNotSaved").popup();}

                    }
            });
        }
```

and on server side you should return `JsonResult` like

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MobileAppointmentEdit(MobileAppointment appointment)
        {
            if (appointment !=null)
            {

             //Do stuff     
             return Json(new {Success = true});

            }

            return Json(new{Success = false});
        }
```

It's worth noting that in case of failure you can send additional fields in your json object like error messages.

Comment: Still get the same problem